# API passing parameter to function to display user

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im just practising working with public API, i just want a simple call for starters, just the username of a user on git hub to display in another div, i have a list of users in my custom api, but when pass the name to the function  i get a weird result ie curl "https://api.github.com/users/"%"22johnpapa"%"22", i dont know where the %22 is coming from, all im passing is a string to add onto the url

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('table tr').click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/api/author/GetName/' + id,
            contentType: "text/plain charset-utf-8",
            data: id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                getDetails(JSON.stringify(data.name));

            }
        });
        }

    );
});//End ready
function getDetails(GitHubUserName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + GitHubUserName,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data.login));
            $('#summaryDisplay').append(data.login);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#summaryDisplay').html('<h3>Error in retrieval</h3>');
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Simply use `getDetails(data.name);` You don't need `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Ah i see, sorry for the newbie question, thanks

Comment: You need that as `JSON.stringify("johnpapa")` will return you `""johnpapa""` and `%22`  is double quotes in URL Encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getDetails(JSON.stringify(data.name));
```

The above line adds double quotation marks to data.name

https://api.github.com/users/' + GitHubUserName

This line will look something like https://api.github.com/users/%22johnpapa%22 
since html char code for a double quote is 22

Either use `getDetails(data.name);` or encode the uri component as `encodeURIComponent('https://api.github.com/users/' + GitHubUserName)`

Comment: Thanks mate, better late then never :-)